# Set mongodb's `maxIndexBuildMemoryUsageMegabytes` setting in conf file

Tags: mongodb

In the mongodb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.maxIndexBuildMemoryUsageMegabytes) for the configuration options it says that I can specify how much RAM index building will consume:

> `maxIndexBuildMemoryUsageMegabytes`:   Limits the amount of memory
>   that simultaneous foreground index builds on one collection may
>   consume for the duration of the builds.

This setting is set after starting the server by executing an administrative command called  `setParameter`.
This is done like this:

`mongo --eval "db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, maxIndexBuildMemoryUsageMegabytes: 700})"`

I would like to specify this amount when the server starts up by putting it in the Configuration File Options. The documentation does not seem to include this option.

#### How can I specify this setting from the mongod.conf file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The different approaches for configuring `setParameter` options (via runtime admin command, config file setting, or command-line option) are listed in the [Synopsis section](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#synopsis) at the top of the MongoDB Server Parameters page you referenced.

You can use `setParameter` key/value pairs in the YAML configuration file.

For example:

```
setParameter:
    maxIndexBuildMemoryUsageMegabytes: 700
```

To confirm this setting has taken effect via the `mongo` shell, use either of:

```
// Check the parameter values parsed from config file or command-line options
db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.setParameter

// Check the current setting of the maxIndexBuildMemoryUsageMegabytes parameter 
db.adminCommand({getParameter: 1, maxIndexBuildMemoryUsageMegabytes: 1})
```